# Can anyone helpe getting 2 level depth dictionary from FirebaseDatabase?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have this FirebaseDatabase structure:

[image]

I need to retrieve the data from Firebase.
Usually I use a function like this:

```
funfunc getWodsFromDataBase () {
    print ("Get Wods From Data Base (AppDelegate)")
    let wodDb = Database.database().reference().child("wods")

    wodDb.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in let snapValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>



        let girl_hero = snapValue["girl_hero"]!
        let nombre = snapValue["nombre"]!
        let wod = Wod(
            girl_hero : girl_hero  as! String,
            nombre : nombre  as! String,
        )
        self.wodsArray.append(wod)
    }
}
```

Its easy to retrieve the first level values, but I don't know how to get every value of the second level ( exercices ) and how to update my wods struct that now are like this :

```
struct Wod {
    var girl_hero : String
    var nombre : String    
    init (){
        self.girl_hero = ""
        self.nombre = ""
    }
    init (
          girl_hero : String,
          nombre : String)
    {
        self.girl_hero = girl_hero
        self.nombre = nombre

    }
}
```

Can any one help me reWriting my Struct and getting the data from Firebase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to loop over the children of the `exercises` node in your snapshot. You do that with something like this:

```
let wodDb = Database.database().reference().child("wods")

wodDb.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in 
    let snapValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>

    let girl_hero = snapValue["girl_hero"]!
    let nombre = snapValue["nombre"]!

    let exercises_snapshot = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "exercises")

    for child in exercises_snapshot.children {
        let exercise_snapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
        let exercise_value = exercise_snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

        let exercise_name = exercise_value["name"]
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The new things in the above code:

- Use [`childSnapshot(forPath:)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#childsnapshotforpath:) to access the `exercises` property as a `DataSnapshot`.
- [Loop over the `DataSnapshot.children`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980821/firebase-swift-3-xcode-8-iterate-through-observe-results) of this.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may helpful for you. use the optional based on your requirements.

```
struct WordSelector:Codable {
    let word:[Exrcices]
}

struct Exrcices:Codable {
    let detail:[Deatil]
    let girl_hero: String
    let nombre: String
}

struct Deatil:Codable {
    let name: String
    let peso: String?
    let reps: String
}
```

Comment: But how can I put the data from Firebase ? can you show me the way ?

Comment: In swift we can parse the data in one line if our struct confirms to Codable  protocol, ex                                                                                                         User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(WordSelector.class);                                  same should be available in your language. Not sure whether it may help you

Comment: it helps me, but I don't know how to call the firebase getter to get this data in Swift

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data chose swift option  this may help you